# Add in already exist text file using java

Tags: java, file, append, printwriter

Im creating a java app in which some text is to be stored in a text file. But store function will run in a loop where every cycle will fetch data from other classes and store in the text file. I want that my text file should store data on each cycle just like you create log. here is some piece of code:

```
public void store(){
        File file = new File("PaperRecord.txt");

        try{
            PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(file);
            fout.println("Paper Name: " + super.getpSame());
            fout.println("Paper Size: " + super.getpSize());
            fout.println("Paper Year: " + super.getpYear());
            fout.println("Paper Author: " + super.getpAuthor());
            fout.println("Paper Description: " + getpDesc());
            fout.println("Paper Signature: " + getpSign());
            fout.println("Email: " + getPEmail());
            fout.println("");
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            //do nothing
        }

    }
```

Calling store function from main using loop:

```
while(!q.isEmpty()){

                        Papers temp = q.remove();
                        temp.print();
                        temp.store();

                    }
```

THe problem currently with this code is that the code create new file paperrecord each time or overrite existing. I want the same file to be increased and updated downward (more text added)

Comment: [java append to file](//stackoverflow.com/q/369760)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: `fout = new PrintWriter( new FileOutputStream( file, true) );`  (not tested.)

Comment: P.S. Catching an exception and then doing nothing is almost always a bad idea.  Please at least call `e.printStackTrace();` on it.  `printStackTrace` is considered sub-optimal, but it's far better than nothing.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

[Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class is your friend dear.

```
try {
    Files.write(Paths.get("PaperRecord.txt"), "new text appended".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
}catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
}
```

Or,a sample working code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class AppendToFileExample {

    private static final String FILENAME = "E:\\test\\PaperRecord.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;

        try {

            String data = " This is new content";

            File file = new File(FILENAME);

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            // true = append file
            fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            bw.write(data);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {

                if (bw != null)
                    bw.close();

                if (fw != null)
                    fw.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what to import for that?

Comment: java.nio.file.*;
Make sure you are using jdk1.7 or later releases.
Cheers

Comment: @TehminaBatool if this solved you problem, do let me know by voting up the answer, thanks.

Comment: Actually I tried, but the function you gave is also overwriting the file not appending

Comment: @TehminaBatool just update my answer with a sample working code, try and let me know

Comment: may i send you java classes on messenger?